# Error HTTP 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

Im trying to upload an application ASP.NET MVC on IIS 7.5 but i have the next problem when i launch it on the browser: Error HTTP 500.19 - Internal Server Error.
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

I dont know how to solve,

any suggest??

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Normally there's some additional information about why its invalid. If there is can you post that, and/or post your web.config with all sensitive information removed?

Comment: Yup, the error is telling you exactly what the problem is, your configuration file (web.config) is corrupted (such as unclosed tags, sections in the wrong area, etc)

Answer (score 0):

**#The Solution#**

1 . install urlrewrite

2 . set permission iuser and IIS_IUSRS

3 . Change Sa Password Sql

4 . Install IIS on The Server Manager

good louck